# Trying to make it so the has:permission makes an error

Tags: python, discord.py

So i am trying to make a say command to my discord.py rewrite bot. But i cant figure out how to make it so it sends a text when the user doesnt have the right permissions

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
async def say (ctx, *, msg2:str):
        await ctx.send(msg2)

@say.error
async def say_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, CheckFailure):
        await ctx.send('You need the **Manage messages** permission to use this command')
```

If a user has the permission Manage messages or adminstrator. I want it to run the say command. If they dont have any of those permissions. i want it to send: "You need the **Manage messages** permission to use this command"

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments to `say_error` are backwards. You can also check for the more specific [`MissingPermissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MissingPermissions) error.

```
@say.error
async def say_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send('You need the **Manage messages** permission to use this command')
    else:
        raise error
```

You can probably generalize this with something like

```
@say.error
async def say_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f'You need the **{", ".join(error.missing_perms)}** permission to use this command')
    else:
        raise error
```